# TFS 2012 authenticates trusted domain users, but not groups - WHY?

Tags: tfs, cross-domain

I am configuring my first Team Foundation Server (TFS) 2012 in a domain called *TFSdomain* that has a one-way trust to another domain where most users will access TFS from, called *UserDomain*. I tried to add *UserDomain\Domain Admins* to the *Team Foundation Administrators* group to let the user *UserDomain\Administrator* have access to the TFS Web Administration. It did not allow access.

The *UserDomain\Domain Admins* is also a member of the local *BUILTIN\Administrators* which is a member of the *Team Foundation Administrators* group. This gives access to *TFSdomain\Administrator*, but not to *UserDomain\Administrator*.

I then added *UserDomain\Administrator* directly to the *Team Foundation Administrators* and tried again. Now I was allowed access.

I then noticed the icon of the *UserDomain\Administrator* entry in the *Team Foundation Administrators* group. It shows the icon for a single user - not for a group, and it is not possible to see group members from the TFS Administration Console.

Have I discovered a bug in TFS 2012, or is there some other reason for this behavior?

Comment: Not sure, but I the reason could be, that you never know who is member of that groups. Imagine the UserDomainGroup has a member from a third domain, that is not trusted by TFSDomain. How should that be handled? You could try to create an AD group in TFSDomain and add a group from UserDomain to it and permit this TFSDomain group in TFS, like a wrapper group.

Comment: Thanks, MikeR for the input. I also thought about a local container group, but as you can see from my edited post, the BUILTIN\Administrators group already contains UserDomain\Domain Admins. Also, global groups can not contain groups from other domains.